# Creating a simple web page to display REST calls or responses

Tags: javascript, rest

I am trying to develop a simple web page which will help our testers to manually test the different REST based routes which we are using.The concept being, I want it to be really simple so that on a button-click a verb will get executed.In a clear way,lets say there are buttons by the name DELETE,PUT,POST,GET let us also assume all the data required(staged or dynamic data) for the above verbs is present,then how should I go about developing the web page?
I am confused whether I should be  using JAXB or something else.I am doing this as a side-project,but to be frank I never have done any front-end or web development,hence the question would seem repetitive or too dumb.I apologize for the same.I don't want to spend time in setting up environment in any specific IDE,but more of handling JSON to be converted to a HTML element as a list(some idea) ,something that will be quick,I have knowledge about Javascript,HTML,XML,but the story remains the same,I really don't know where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: The Chrome extension "REST Console" may fits your needs.

Comment: Hi @STM,I already have given a demo to them.But,this web page will help me increase my skillset into some web technologies,also will give the testers a GUI to actually see the data being populated,deleted etc.Though thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: _"handling JSON to be converted to a HTML element as a list"_ - If I was testing REST calls I would prefer the test tool to display the raw result, i.e., if the server returns JSON I'd want to see the JSON. If you convert it to HTML then the testers can't tell if an incorrect result is because of the REST part or because of the test tool.

Comment: @nnnnnn,thank you for the suggestion,but still if we assume maintaining the response obtained as a JSON is maintained and not changed to a list or any other HTML Element,then would the notion of having buttons for each verb ok?I mean what will I use behind the button? Javascript? is it possible for any references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of api consoles out there that can integrate with your REST platform and provide a "playground" environment for testing and even for developer testing. The one that we use currently is swagger (swagger-core and swagger-ui) which is open source. Have a look here : [Swagger](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki). there are some paid ones as well such as [Apigee](https://apigee.com/about/) but it introduces a whole new component to your deployed application (which swagger does as well but at a lot smaller scale) which we didn't see a need for.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help and suggestions.After a lot of Googling I came to know for Web designers who are just taking their first step Bootstrap will provide a lot of help in designing the web pages.Along with that for REST Request management I am thinking of using XmlHttpRequest,and lastly for dynamic content I am planning to use MVVM frameworks.This is what I have planned lets see how it goes.